# Is "Who are" omitted in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

Never miss a chance to make ***those watching*** you laugh.

My question is that does the sentence elide "who are"? Can I rewrite it as Never miss a chance to make ***those who are*** watching you laugh?

Comment: The current answer is OK. You might also think about switching to "the audience" or "your audience" or some such.  Also, good handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both correct and can have the exact same meaning. However, when you say "Never miss a chance to make those who are watching you laugh," it can also be perceived as if you are talking about the people who are watching him/her right now (a specific situation at hand). The sentence without "who are" feels like a piece of general life advice that you would give to someone (like a standup comedian).